# Google Maps Terrain View By Default

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to figure out how to make my google maps embed default to the "Terrain View" and disable other options like Satellite view and Street View. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's my code...

Here's how it currently renders: http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/7299/screenshot20111220at125.png

```
var map;
var middle_earth_MORADOR = new google.maps.LatLng(38, 0);

    function initialize() {

        // Define Styles
        var styles = [ 
            {
                //featureType: "all", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { visibility: "on" }, { hue: "#e5f5fb" } ]
            }
        ];


        // Default map options
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: middle_earth_MORADOR,
            backgroundColor: "#000"
        };

        var locations = [
            <?php foreach ($Projects as $Project) {             

                $oProjectPhotos = new clsProjectPhotos($Project['idProject']);
                $photos = $oProjectPhotos->getProjectPhotos();
                echo '["'.$Project["Name"].'", '.$Project["gmapslat"].', '.$Project["gmapslng"].', "'.$Project["CountryName"].'"],';
                echo "\n";
                echo "\t\t";
            }
            ?>  
        ];


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
        var styledMapOptions = {
            map: map,
            name: "map"
        }
        var build =  new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,styledMapOptions);
        map.mapTypes.set('map', build);
        map.setMapTypeId('map');

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(
                '<div>' + locations[i][0] + '</div>'+
                '<div>' + locations[i][4] + '</div>'+
                '<div>' + locations[i][5] + '</div>'+
                '<div>' + locations[i][6] + '</div>'
              );
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }

          })(marker, i));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the map types those your user can choose:

```
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    //center: brooklyn,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.565, -46.6565),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
       mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
```

Where [mapTypeControlOptions](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeControlOptions) is the type control options, and [mapTypeId](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeId) is the default map type.

Comment: This worked well. It now limits only "TERRAIN" view on the UI. The only problem is it is not set to TERRAIN view on the document load.

Comment: This did not seem to work. Tried playing around with it in a variety of ways after looking at the API for it.

Comment: I think, the only error was in the center attribute. I´ve copied from google samples. You have to specify a latlng.